# Figma: How do you most efficiently create master component in-context and then move it to a separate frame/page

Tags: figma, components

I believe it is a known best practice when working on small Figma files to have all Master components on a separate page or frame. There are a number of benefits to this, which I won't go into here, and if you don't want to go to the trouble of publishing a Library (for smaller, one-off projects), it's a good practice, buuut.....

If you like creating components in-context (or you don't think it will be a component and then you realize it should be), it's hella difficult to get that Master component onto its own page, while leaving an Instance in its place.

Let me give an example: You are creating a button. You add an icon and some text. You thought it was a one-off and you created it in-context (i.e.: you're designing this button on the same page as the rest of your UI so you can determine how big to make everything, how the colours look, what font to use, etc.). And you place it carefully into your design and it looks great. Then you realize, "snap I want another button that's just like this one - I better make it a component". So you take that button you made, and turn it into a component.

But wait, that Master component is now embedded inside your design - and you want it on a Master Components page. Oh sure, you can cut it and paste it, but then you have to drag an instance and get it all re-aligned inside your design.

A sensible piece of software would allow you to move the Master component elsewhere whilst leaving an Instance in its place. Or would allow you to copy an Instance to your Master Components page and then Swap the Master and the Instance. Or any number of methods I haven't thought of yet.

What's the method you use to get around this limitation?